# SSIS - Entity Framework - {Model}.resource.dll is missing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ssis, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I´m writing a SSIS Package with a Script Component. In this script component I´m trying to etablish a Entity Framework Connection, but I´m getting following error:

> Could not load file or assembly '{Model}.resource.dll' or one of its dependencies error

{Model} is the dll containing my EF6 Code first model. I don´t have any {Model}.resource.dll available.

If I run the same code in a console application it is working and there is no .resource.dll

I use the DBConfiguration possibility to get rid of the app.config file, because SSIS is not supporting it.

```
public class ModelConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public ModelConfig()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("mssqllocaldb"));

        this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient",
           System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

SSIS is adding locale information to the thread. Entity Framework has a bug with locale information.

This helps:

```
public ScriptMain()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
```